# Flow agents one by one anylogic

Tags: java, simulation, simulator, anylogic

I'm simulating a Process in anylogic in which I need my agents to flow from a queue to a Service one by one, and only when the service is empity (namely when the preceding agent has finished with it).
How can I do? I tried using an Hold between the queue and the service that's true only when the service is empty, and it is ok, but I need the agents to flow one by one and not all together.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a "wait" block before the service block and when your service block is empty you do the following:

```
if(wait.size()>0 && service.size()==0)
wait.free(wait.get(0))
```

you have to put this code in 2 places:

- on seize of the service block
- On enter in the wait block

Another way of doing this is to replace the service block by a combination of seize delay release and you use a restricted area start and restricted area end between the seize block and you restrict the number of agents to 1 (if you want to have a maximum of 1 in the service queue) or put the restrictions between the service block if you want the queue to always be zero.

Choose your favorite one

Comment: Alternatively, if applicable to your system, only have 1 resource in the resource pool you use :-)